# Confusion about the online booking of Lego House tickets

Tags: bookings, denmark

When booking the ticket online for Lego House in Billund, on some dates there is an option to choose a specific entry time, on some dates there is only a line of text saying "Book your space - click here", and on some dates there are both. I'm really confused.

Do I need to choose a specific entry time to visit the Experience Zones or not (some travel guides say that you must be allocated an entry time slot)? What is the difference between the two options? If I choose a timeslot, am I not allowed in if I miss it? If I choose "Book your space - click here", am I allowed in any time of the day? I hope the website can offer clearer explanations on this point.

Answer (score 1):

These LEGOLAND® FAQs may help clarify (as referenced on its USA sites):

> [**Why do I have to book into a time slot?**](https://dallas-support.legolanddiscoverycenter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003143032-Why-do-I-have-to-book-into-a-time-slot-)
>
> When booking your ticket you will be asked to select a date and time for your arrival.
>
> This helps us make your experience more enjoyable by reducing queue times, speeding up your entry in to the attraction and reducing crowding.
>
> Please arrive within your pre-booked 15 minute timeslot. Once inside the attraction, you may stay as long as you like.
>
> We strongly advise pre-booking in advance to guarantee admission and avoid disappointment.
>
> [**What if I'm running late for my time slot?**](https://philadelphia-support.legolanddiscoverycenter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003120332-What-if-I-m-running-late-for-my-time-slot-)
>
> We can still admit you up to two hours after your entry time and will do our best to get you in as quickly as possible however there may be a prolonged wait.
>
> We therefore strongly advise when booking your ticket to make sure you choose a time that suits you and your family.
>
> We strongly advise pre-booking in advance to guarantee admission and avoid disappointment.